# REACT : change button color when active does not work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I want my side bar button to change color when I route to its linked page.
my code changes the color and the color remains the same even if I route to a different page.
here is my code:

```js
lass Sidebar extends Component<{}, {}> {
  style = this.getBtnClassName();
  render() {
    return (
      <aside className="sidebar">
        <nav className="nav">
          <LinkButton to="/timer" label="Timer" cssPrefix={this.getBtnClassName()} styles={['block']} />
          <LinkButton to="/reports" label="Report" cssPrefix={this.getBtnClassName()} styles={['block']} />
        </nav>
      </aside>
    );
  }
  getBtnClassName() {
    if (window.location.href === 'http://localhost:3000/timer') {
      return 'nav_active';
    } else {
      return 'nav__btn';
    }
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Are you able to setup a working example of the code on SlackBlitz (or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use className instead.
Start out by simply making your getBtnClassname simply use the `window.location.pathname` and not the `window.location.href`, then it can also work when deployed to any website.

```
    getBtnClassName() {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/timer') {
      return 'nav_active';
    } else {
      return 'nav__btn';
    }
  }
```

From there, all you really need to do is call the function to assign the returned value of `this.getBtnClassName` to be a classname you wish to apply.

```
<button to="/timer" label="Timer" className={this.getBtnClassName()}>{this.getBtnClassName()}</button>
```

---

You could also assign the correct class to a variable inside the render, which when you only have 2 classes in your case is a little cleaner.

```
 const btnClass = window.location.pathname === "/timer" ? "nav_active" : "nav__btn"
```

```
<button to="/reports" label="Report" className={btnClass}>{btnClass}</button>
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scltse

Answer (score 1):

you can use NavLink from react-router-dom 
and use the prop  activeClassName

ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md